# Ethernet doesn't work after using Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, ethernet

I tried asking the question at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750280/windows-ethernet-doesnt-work-after-using-ubuntu-16-04-in-dual-boot) but didn't get any answer so I am asking it here.

I am using a pc with dual boot `Windows 10` and `Ubuntu 16.04`. each time I use ubuntu and shutdown and then login to windows the Ethernet doesn't work upon troubleshooting it shows error `one or more network protocols are missing on this computer` .

I found the solution to the above is running the command `netsh winsock reset` on command prompt.

However I have to restart windows again for the command to take effect which is a pain,so I am looking for a permanent fix.

```
summary : use ubuntu -> shutdown ubuntu-> login windows -> ethernet doesn'twork -> 
          fix via cmd -> have to restart windows again(pain)
```

Comment: try these suggested fixes: http://appuals.com/best-fix-one-or-more-network-protocols-are-missing/    Assuming you have one, is your cable modem by chance an "Arris Interactive, L.L.C. tm602g"?

Comment: @Argonauts i have a Realtek card. i tried these methods but no success

Comment: You have a realtek cable modem? Also - since one of the items on the list was your current workaround, the assumption was that some of these setting changes would result in at least a temporary resolution as does the network stack reset with netsh. If you provide the results from trying those things, good and bad, someone may be able to assist. Disabling and enabling the NIC did nothing?